# WhenActivated not called in ViewModel

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, reactiveui

I'm using ReactiveUI 8.7.2 to create android/iOS Xamarin.Native app with shared ViewModels. I want to use `WhenActivated` in Fragments and corresponding ViewModels, but it's only being called in Fragments. Here's my code:

Base ViewModel:

```
public class ReactiveViewModel : ReactiveObject, ISupportsActivation
{
    public ViewModelActivator Activator { get; }

    public ReactiveViewModel(ViewModelActivator viewModelActivator)
    {
        Activator = viewModelActivator;

        this.WhenActivated((Action<IDisposable> disposable) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Activated BaseViewModel");
        });
    }

    public ReactiveViewModel() : this(new ViewModelActivator())
    {
    }
}
```

Base Fragment:

```
public abstract class BaseReactiveFragment<T> : ReactiveUI.AndroidSupport.ReactiveFragment<T> where T : ReactiveViewModel
{
    public BaseReactiveFragment()
    {
        this.WhenActivated(disposable =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Activated BaseFrament");
        });
    }
}
```

ViewModel

```
public class MyViewModel : ReactiveViewModel
{
    public MyViewModel()
    {
        this.WhenActivated((Action<IDisposable> disposable) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Activated ViewModel");
        });
    }
}
```

Fragment

```
public class MyFragment : BaseReactiveFragment<MyViewModel>
{
    public MyFragment() 
    {
        this.WhenActivated((Action<IDisposable> disposable)=>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Activated Fragment");
        });
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you share where you are assigning the ViewModel property of MyFragment/BaseReactiveFragment?

Comment: I was not aware that I needed to do so. I assumed they're being instantiated in the background. Added VM initialization and it fixed the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Posting an extended version of my comment as an answer for completeness.]

Make sure you assign the ViewModel property of MyFragment/BaseReactiveFragment. The ViewModel property is only automatically assigned if you're using ReactiveUI's routing infrastructure e.g. [RoutedViewHost](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/c9746da4988d1fe8fda1b4dc34f0a6b390818e40/src/ReactiveUI/Platforms/windows-common/RoutedViewHost.cs#L113) or [ViewModelViewHost](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/c9746da4988d1fe8fda1b4dc34f0a6b390818e40/src/ReactiveUI/Platforms/apple-common/ViewModelViewHost.cs#L108). But because Android uses a different mechanism (intents) for Activity construction, ReactiveUI.Android doesn't include those helpers.

Glad to hear it was an easy fix. Happy coding!